# Open SSL and recognising certificates

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables, osx-mavericks

I can type

```
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/Users/MyComputer/Desktop/certificate.crt
```

to get my open SSL working as expected on OSX, what should I do to make this permanent? Put that line in .bash_profile ? just put the certificate in a magic place?

Comment: Same question here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/76115/where-is-ruby-looking-for-ssl-cert-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want permanent for a particular user or for all the user?

For a particular user, edit `$(HOME)/.bash_profile` by putting this line there.

For all, edit /etc/paths.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135688/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x) might help you.